# Highlight questions with favorited tags on StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

I would like for StackExchange.com to highlight questions with my favorite tags as well. I know I can filter by favorite tags, but I would like to see all questions and highlight the ones that match a tag of mine in that website, just like on StackOverflow. Has this been considered?

Comment: You mean on the "Hot Questions" page?

Comment: Yes and filtered questions

Comment: You can already do that on Filtered Questions with the "favorite tags" filter. ([see here](http://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags))

Comment: But I don't want other questions to be filtered out

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question in its entirety. This is an interesting suggestion...I don't pay much attention to those pages, but I'm sure others do.

Comment: Ironically, I wish SO worked like SE did!

Answer (score 1):

That would mean showing the recent questions on the sites you have an account, and favorite tags, and then highlighting the questions that use one of your favorite tags. That is expensive, computationally speaking, and I don't see any reason to show all the questions, when you are interested in the ones using your favorite tags.

If you want to see the questions using your favorite tags, highlighted and mixed between the other questions, you can check out the single Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Well. I keep in tags topics that I know the most or are most interested in. It doesn't mean I don't want to see other topics at all

Comment: In that case, you can look at the single Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It is annoying to have several tabs so I usually end up just in Stackoverflow and forget about other sites.

Comment: If you want to see the front page of every Stack Exchange site where you have an account, that is the only way you have. Imagine the CPU resources required to show the questions present in the front page of any Stack Exchange site where you have an account.

Comment: Well,I don't know the details of the implementation of this engine but you already can have the front page of every Stack Exchange site where you have an account. You just will need to add the tags of each side in the transaction the rest is possible to be done by  client-side and considering you already transfer all the questions, transfering the tags doesn't look that expensive in contrast